# How to change the uitableviews style in code in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I want to change the uitableview's stype in viewdidiload in swift.
but it gives an error "Can not assign the result of this expression

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    let names = ["Gulshan","Mitesh","Rahul","roma"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any xadditional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableview.style  = UITableViewStyle.Grouped
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do that while initializing in init with frame method.

See example:

```
var tableview1 = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 160,320), style: UITableViewStyle.Grouped)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the tableview style dinamically, you have to do it in your xib file or storyboard if you have one.
If you don't use a storyboard or a xib, and prefer to create the tableview programmatically, specify the style while creating the tableview using the 
- initWithFrame:style: method.

Bye
D.